# Call mkdir() once in method of controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form which uploads multiple files. No of files uploaded once are uploaded in a unique directory. The problem I am facing right now is that For one user I want to run the `mkdir()` once. Don't know how to do it exactly.

Controller.php

```
class Upload_file extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }
    function upload_it()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $uniqueID = uniqid(); 
        mkdir("application/uploads/".$uniqueID);

        $config['upload_path'] = 'application/uploads/'.$uniqueID;
        $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->set_allowed_types('*');

        $data['upload_data'] = '';
        if (!$this->upload->do_multi_upload('files')) {
            $data = array('msg' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        } 
        else
        {
              $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data();
        }
        $this->load->vars($data);

        $this->load->view('upload');
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<form target="upload_target" id="fileupload" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('upload_file/upload_it'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="fileUpload btn btn-warning">
    <span>Browse</span>
    <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[]" class="upload" />
</div>
    <input id="uploadFile" style="width: 160px; margin-top: 30px;float: left;height: 35px;" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />
    <button id="btnupload" style="padding: 4.5px; float:left;margin-top: 30px;border-radius: 0px;" disabled="disabled" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span></button>

</form>
```

Comment: its an good practice to check if folder already exist before creating.

Comment: Don't understand your problem. It looks OK what you have written there?!

Answer (score 4):

I dont know if I understood your problem, but I guess you should just check if the folder exists first, then create it:

```
if (!file_exists("application/uploads/".$uniqueID)) {
    mkdir("application/uploads/".$uniqueID);
}
```

Comment: Every time the `$uniqueID = uniqid();` is run the new value is created. I want to check that if its created once the next time should not be called.

Comment: the only way you can check if the $uniqueId is already created in the past is to ask if the folder exists. this is probably not a good way to do what you meant. maybe you should use a Mysql column that has an Auto Increment on it, then use it as your uniqueId.

Comment: Ok But this function is called 1 to many times by person at the time of registration then how to check that column id is incremented or not?

Comment: you should create that userId/uniqueId before calling your upload function, just pass that id to that function, this way 1 user should always have the same uniqueId.

Comment: Same way i can call the `uniqu()` from calling upload function and pass that value further to `makdir()`. But this is the main problem i m not getting not to call and pass values. As upload is call once the button is submitted.

Comment: but if you upload multiple files from the same user, the best thing to do is to create that uniqueId before you call the upload function.

Comment: This is what I wanted to ask in the question but couldn't deliver well.

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure first either folder already exit or not, and until check with the new folder name

Example:-
Create a new filed in users table, having name folder name, and first time if folder column is empty then create a new one as given in blow:

```
$folder_path = "application/uploads/".$uniqueID;
while (file_exists($folder_pat)) {
    $uniqueID = $this->uniqid();   // get the next unique id
    $folder_path = "application/uploads/".$uniqueID;
}

mkdir($folder_path);
```

once folder is created, then when ever you want to upload any file againt that user then first check in db either it' already exist or not, if not exit then create a new dir. else use the previous one that already created.

Comment: Its giving an error undefined variable name $uniqueID.

Comment: I actually want to create directory once for  one user either he uploads 1 file at a time or ten files in ten times. I want them to be in one folder.

Comment: modified the answer, please follow the insturctions.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this little script to create a dir (recursively or not) or use an existing one :

```
private function _r_mkdir($path, $mode = 0755, $recursive = true)
{
    if(empty($path)){
        return false;
    }

    if($recursive) {
        $toDo = substr($path, 0, strrpos($path, '/'));
        if($toDo !== '.' && $toDo !== '..'){
            $this->_r_mkdir($toDo, $mode);
        }
    }

    if(!is_dir($path)){
        mkdir($path, $mode);
    }

    return true;
}
```

And in your function, you can call it like this :

```
$relativePath = './uploads/'.$path;
$this->_r_mkdir($relativePath);
```

**NOTE**
I don't recommend you to create the folder /uploads/ in your /Application/ folder. Why ? Because assets are not part of your application code flow. It's independent. Let's say you want to zip your code to send it on an other server (or for someone), you may not want to get all the Gigas of uploaded files in it.